# How do I get around a nil object being created in my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So this is my controller for my `Home#Index`

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @daily_entries = current_user.daily_entries
    @weekly_entries = current_user.weekly_entries
    @daily_entry = current_user.daily_entries.new
    @weekly_entry = current_user.weekly_entries.new
  end
end
```

The reason this is like this is because I am trying to render two form partials for the creation of both the `DailyEntry` and `WeeklyEntry` object types on my `Home#Index.html.erb`.

But, once the page loads, it automatically instantiates an object of each `DailyEntry` and `WeeklyEntry` with all nil values. So whenever I do a simple `@daily_entries.each` loop, it comes upon a record with lots of nil values - even though the record is not `nil` itself.

Like this:

```
 #<DailyEntry id: nil, breakfast: nil, snack_1: nil, lunch: nil, snack_2: nil, dinner: nil, water_intake: nil, workout: nil, notes: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: 1>]
```

Aside from removing the `current_user.daily_entries.new` calls, how do I get around these nil objects for my `each` loops on this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found works:

In my `HomeController.rb`:

```
@daily_entries = current_user.daily_entries.where(:id == true)
```

That filters out initialized, but unsaved records.

Comment: It looks like I didn't understand the problem, you could also use `@daily_entries = current_user.daily_entries.reject(&:new?)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the "confident code" approach. In this particular case, abuse the methods such as `to_s` and `to_i`. Examples work better:

```
@daily_entries.each do |daily_entry|
  # If it's a String, nothing happens, if it's nil, empty string will be returned.
  string_val = daily_entry.breakfast.to_s

  # If it's a Fixnum, nothing happens, if it's nil, 0 will be returned.
  int_val = daily_entry.id.to_i
end
```

Watch [this video with Avdi Grimm](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8J0j2xJFgQ), it explains this stuff about confident code really well.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: The thing is, all I want to do is to output the various values of `daily_entry` - not really checking the values.